# Ambiguous in the namespace issue, even after removing previous control

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, namespaces

I was using a control in my application and then decided to make some customizations to it so I modified the control and built it and removed the old control from my project and dropped the new one in. Now I am getting the error :'AutocompleteMenu" is ambiguous in the namespace 'AutocompleteMenuNS'.

Like I said I had removed the old control from the project so why is it still saying it is ambigous? Do I have to go through the project and remove every last entry of this control? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does this question also have the [c#] tag?

Comment: Because it is not language specific, it could happen to both c# users and vb.net users, thus a wider support group? Although the control is c# and the project it is being dropped into is vb.net. What is the issue?

Comment: I was just curious. The compiler message seems to come from VB.NET. I don't know if it's language independent, but maybe so.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting your bin and obj folders, then rebuilding your project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I am still encountering this issue  though after completing the steps you mentioned.

Comment: It's going to be tough to speculate further without seeing all the changes you made.  Can you show a diff file or something?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a "trick", but try a "Find in files" in ALL your project files, and remove the old namespace

Visual mismatches when you remove an old namespace ...